# Converting selected rows to column using perl script

Tags: r, perl, bioinformatics, bioperl

I need a Perl script to concatenation the line..

I have more than 1000 gene name (>pmpI) and its function (polymorphic outer membrane protein) its is in separate line and i wish to join the function of the gene near to the gene name, so that it can be easy in future to visualize and save it for further reference.

Eg: Files content looks like this

```
>pmpG
 polymorphic outer membrane protein
>pmpH
 polymorphic outer membrane protein
>CTA_0953
 hypothetical protein
>pmpI
 polymorphic outer membrane protein
```

I tried to do manually in excel manually, but its not possible for many files, so i thought to get help from programmer..

I need Perl script to concatenation the lines

Program out put should be like this:

```
>pmpG      polymorphic outer membrane protein
>pmpH      polymorphic outer membrane protein
>CTA_0953  hypothetical protein
>pmpI      polymorphic outer membrane protein
```

Answer (score 3):

As a single-line command, this would be

```
perl -n -e 's/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; next unless $_ ne ""; if (/^[>]/) { $n = $_; } else { printf "%-11s%s\n", $n, $_; }' < data.txt
```

For clarification, when put in a perl program, it would look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {                            # iterate over all lines
    s/^\s+//;                           # remove whitespace at the beginning...
    s/\s+$//;                           # ...and the end of the line
    next unless $_ ne "";               # ignore empty lines
    if (/^[>]/) { $n = $_; }            # if line starts with >, remember it
    else { printf "%-11s%s\n", $n, $_;  # otherwise output the remembered 
}                                       # content and the current line
```

This accepts your content as input, so it would be called with `perl program.pl < data.txt`.

The content is expected to be contained in `data.txt`; modify this to your actual filename.

Answer (score 0):

With some explanatory comments...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

# Store the current line
my $line;
while (<DATA>) {
  # Remove the newline
  chomp;
  # If the line starts with '>'
  if (/^>/) {
    # Output the current $line
    # (if we have one)
    say $line if $line;
    # Set $line to this line
    $line = $_;
  } else {
    # Append this line to $line
    $line .= "\t$_";
  }
}

# Output the current line
say $line;

__DATA__
>pmpG
 polymorphic outer membrane protein
>pmpH
 polymorphic outer membrane protein
>CTA_0953
 hypothetical protein
>pmpI
 polymorphic outer membrane protein
```